# url in CRAN extension manual

Tags: r, package, cran

Aesthetics question about CRAN manuals.  How do you make urls from the `Description` field red and function when clicked (like the first url in the `URL` field)?  The only one that appears red in a manual is the first url in th `URL` field, and some of the links (such as in `BugReports` field) don't work..

Here's my Description (chopped down):

```
Package: package
Type: Package
Title: stuff
Version: 0.2.1
Date: 2012-05-09
Author: me
Maintainer: bob <bob@gmail.com>
Depends:
    R (>= 2.15),
Imports:
    gridExtra
Suggests:
    plyr
LazyData: TRUE
Description: This package is awesome.
Note: qdap is not compiled for Mac users.  Installation instructions for Mac
    user or other OS users having difficulty installing qdap please visit:
    http://trinker.github.com/qdap_install/installation
License: GPL-2
URL: http://trinker.github.com/qdap/ https://github.com/trinker/qdap
BugReports: https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues
Collate:
    'adjacency_matrix.R'
```

And the manual:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/qdap.pdf

Comment: <guess>maybe it doesn't like `https`?</guess>

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich your guess was correct.  It doesn't turn the links in BugReports red but all links work now.